# MS SQL Server - Get Values Before and After a Delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, string-formatting

I’m trying to figure out a way to select specific values from a String that is separated by a delimiter, in this case commas. I need to report each value after a comma in a separate field. I’ll include an example below for reference:

```
String: FirstVal,FirstName,HomeAddress,HomeCity,HomeCountry
```

This “FirstVal” value can be ignored, I don’t need to report that one, but I need to report the one after the first comma, and each individual one after each of the other commas, each in a separate field. Also, I don’t control length of the String or the length of each value, in other words there can be an infinite number of values with different lengths separated by commas. However, I do know the values can only be VARCHAR, so conversion/casting won’t be a problem. One last thing, I’m on SQL Server 2012, so the STRING_SPLIT Function unfortunately can’t be used, in case someone has a way of doing this by employing that Function.

Since the first value can be ignored, this is what I need to report from the String:

```
NameField: FirstName
AddressField: HomeAddress
AddressCity: HomeCity
AddressCountry: HomeCountry
```

I’ve been looking through the forum for a viable solution, and I’ve been experimenting with some iterations of CHARINDEX, but that doesn’t seem to be cutting it, so I’d really appreciate some assistance!

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: I don't understand the output. Are you wanting that as a table and the column names are NameField, AddressField etc?

Comment: Hey Sean, that’s right, sorry if that looks a bit confusing, I had each field name in a separate line but they all got jumbled together when I hit “post”. I don’t actually need to create a Table or Insert into one, I can actually just do Select into each of the fields.

Comment: If it's possible, you could write SQL CLR function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one easy way to tackle this one. It is using the DelimitedSplit8K function from Jeff Moden which you can find [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function).

```
declare @String varchar(200) = 'FirstVal,FirstName,HomeAddress,HomeCity,HomeCountry'

select NameField = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 2 then s.Item end)
    , AddressField = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 3 then s.Item end)
    , AddressCity = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 4 then s.Item end)
    , AddressCountry = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 5 then s.Item end)
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@String, ',') s
```

Output:

```
NameField   AddressField    AddressCity AddressCountry
FirstName   HomeAddress     HomeCity    HomeCountry
```

Comment: The link should be https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function   I tried to Edit, but my firewall must be blocking an edit.

Comment: @MAkin haha not sure what I did there. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a little XML.  Clearly you can add, eliminate and/or rename columns, but dynamically named columns would require dynamic SQL.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'FirstVal,FirstName,HomeAddress,HomeCity,HomeCountry'

Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
```

Returns

```
Pos1        Pos2        Pos3        Pos4        Pos5
FirstVal    FirstName   HomeAddress HomeCity    HomeCountry
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions gentlemen, much appreciated! I ended up going with the DelimitedSplit8K Function in this case, works like a charm!